Speed up build time of application in Cloud Build
I run simple Angular application in Google Cloud Platform. Everything works fine but I realized that build time takes really long. I tried to introduce caching of node_modules to make installing deps quicker but it seems to me it might be much faster.
Here’s my config
steps:
  # Install
  - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/restore_cache'
    id: 'Restoring NPM modules cache'
    args:
      - --bucket=gs://${PROJECT_ID}_cloudbuild
      - --key=npm-build-cache-$( checksum package.json )-$( checksum package-lock.json )
      - --key_fallback=npm-build-cache-

  - name: 'node:$_NODE_VERSION'
    entrypoint: npm
    id: 'Installing NPM dependencies'
    args:
      - ci
      - install
      - --prefer-offline
      - --cache=.npm

  - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/save_cache'
    id: 'Saving .npm cache'
    args:
      - --bucket=gs://${PROJECT_ID}_cloudbuild
      - --key=npm-build-cache-$( checksum package.json )-$( checksum package-lock.json )
      - --path=.npm
      - --no-clobber
    waitFor: [ 'Installing NPM dependencies' ]

  # Build
  - name: 'node:$_NODE_VERSION'
    entrypoint: npm
    args: [ 'run', 'build' ]
    # Deploy
  - name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
    args: [ 'deploy', '--only=hosting' ]


I know I can try to speed up build step using docker caching
https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/speeding-up-builds#using_a_cached_docker_image
But how to apply it to installing deps? Maybe you have some other advices what else I can do.

did you try to increase CPU for your Builds? https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/increase-vcpu-for-builds

@guillaumeblaquiere it apparently speed up the build and deploy parts but restoring npm still takes around 40 seconds.

In addition to add more CPU in your build instance, I understood why it takes so much time.
If you have a look at the node module directory it's a nightmare for file systems! There is a lot, a lot, a lot of files.
Problem with Cloud Storage, it's not a file system and it opens a HTTP connection for each file it uploads/downloads.

But there is a solution (I've already implemented). Here the principle:

before uploading the node module, perform a tar (no compression) of the directory. (optionally gzip it)
upload this tar to GCS
When you want to restore the deps, download the tar
untar the file (optionally ungzip it before the untar).

You will severely decrease the npm module save and restore duration!
